# Display pandas columns - wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Say I have a row of column headers, and associated values in a Pandas Dataframe:

```
print df

A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J       K
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11
```

how do I go about displaying them like the following:

```
print df

A       B       C       D       E       
1       2       3       4       5       

F       G       H       I       J       
6       7       8       9       10      

K
11
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: @WeNYoBen  That won't do it, I am already familiar with those options. I could just slice the frame and perform 3 print statements, but I was looking for something more formal.

Comment: can you post what you've tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### custom function

```
def new_repr(self):
    g = self.groupby(np.arange(self.shape[1]) // 5, axis=1)
    return '\n\n'.join([d.to_string() for _, d in g])

print(new_repr(df))

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5

   F  G  H  I   J
0  6  7  8  9  10

    K
0  11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 20)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', True)
 df
   A  B  C  D  E  \
0  1  2  3  4  5   

   F  G  H  I   J  \
0  6  7  8  9  10   

    K  
0  11
```

Comment: Upvoted, but going with the function as the end code is going to be turned into an exe, and I don't want to gamble on pd.options being non compilable.